# How to create a button counter in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched all over the internet and can't seem to find the answer. Can you please help me create a like button counter (like facebook) in MVC.

Comment: Do you want Facebook like button with counter or what??

Comment: what did you tried so far? Please edit your question.

Comment: Can you provide an image or explain what you want a little more clearly?

Comment: I want to create my own button counter, to count the number of likes for that particular post. Using Model, View Controller in Asp.net and store that counter in the sql database, for each post

Answer (score 1):

You should create some kind of badge, via css, and make AJAX call everytime someone press the button, on the success result of that call, you receive the actual number, and replace into the badge